# Is it possible to make smart contract trustlessly know addresses of RSK pegnatories in real-time?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bitcoin, rsk

Is there any way to use a smart contract on RSK to query the addresses of all current pegnatories? And to do so without relying on 3rd party oracles on RSK?

For context: The intention here is to make smart contract allocate a part of incomes generated from fees to the pegnatories to contribute to the RSK chain's sustainability and security.

Note that this is a follow up question [to this prior one about the RSK Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68773420/194982).

Comment: Noticed that this question happens to have a close vote on it. My view is that this is a legit question about an API with possible answers in either Javascript or Solidity.

Answer (score 5):

Using web3.js you should be able to do the following:

```js
let fedSize = await bridge.methods
    .getFederationSize().call();
let pks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < fedSize; i++) {
    let pk = await bridge.methods
        .getFederatorPublicKeyOfType(i, 'rsk').call();
    pks.push(pk);
}
let addresses = pks.map((pk) => (keccak256(pk).substr(12)));
```

To initialise the `bridge` object, you'll need to use the ABI for RSK Bridge precompile, as described in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68773568/194982).

Answer (score 5):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./Bridge.sol";

contract Federation {
    function getBridge() private pure returns (Bridge) {
        return Bridge(address(0x01000006));
    }
    function getFederationSize() private view returns ( int256 ) {
        return getBridge().getFederationSize();
    }
    function getFederatorPublicKeyOfType ( int256 index, string memory atype ) private view returns ( bytes memory ) {
        return getBridge().getFederatorPublicKeyOfType(index, atype);
    }
    function getFederatorKeys() public view returns( bytes[] memory ) {
        int256 fedSize = getFederationSize();
        bytes[] memory keys = new bytes[](uint(fedSize));
        for (int256 i = 0; i < fedSize; i += 1) {
            keys[uint(i)] = getFederatorPublicKeyOfType(i, 'rsk');
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

To do this on-chain (in a smart contract), you can create a Solidity function (`getFederatorKeys()` in the code above) that does the same thing as
[the web3.js answer from @bguiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68776491/194982)
which is to call `getFederationSize`, and then `getFederatorPublicKeyOfType` within a loop.

Note that you will need to modify `Bridge.sol` interface,
such that the signature of `getFederatorPublicKeyOfType` has `view`

```
-  function getFederatorPublicKeyOfType ( int256 index, string calldata atype ) external returns ( bytes memory);
+  function getFederatorPublicKeyOfType ( int256 index, string calldata atype ) external view returns ( bytes memory);
```

Later this function may be called from web3.js like this

```
const fedPubKeys = await federation.methods.getFederatorKeys().call()
```